# Как произвести сумму полей в Django?

Tags: python, django

Эксперт (**Expert**) заполняет Опросный лист (**Blank_list**) с выбранным Сотрудником (**Employee**) и выставляет оценки(**lvl1, lvl2, lvl3**). 
Будет несколько Экспертов, соответственно будет 5 Опросных листов с Оценками.
Для подведения итогов была создана модель **EmployeeCard**, чтобы собрать сумму всех оценок и вывести среднюю для определенного Сотрудника.
Как суммировать оценки с Опросных листов?

**models.py**:

```
ANSWER_TYPES = (
    (0, 0),
    (1, 1),
    )

class Expert(models.Model):
    expertname = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    position = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)

class Employee(models.Model):
    employeename = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    position = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)

class Blank_list(models.Model):
    expert_name = models.ForeignKey(Expert, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    employee_name = models.ForeignKey(Employee, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    lvl_1 = models.IntegerField('Indicator1:1', choices=ANSWER_TYPES, blank=0)
    lvl_2 = models.IntegerField('Indicator1:2', choices=ANSWER_TYPES, blank=0)
    lvl_3 = models.IntegerField('Indicator1:3', choices=ANSWER_TYPES, blank=0)

class EmployeeCard(models.Model):
    blank_list = models.ManyToManyField(Blank_list, null=True, ) #несколько опросных листов привязанных к работнику
    #но я не уверен, что я правильно определил blank_list как модель с ManyToManyField
    employee_name = models.ForeignKey(Employee, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    sum_of_all_blank_list = ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

на мой взгляд ты зря добавил модель `EmployeeCard` у тебя уже есть привязка `Blank_list` и `Employee` и дополнительная не особо нужна.
Для того, что бы было проще обращаться к бланк листам из модели `Employee`  я бы немного изменил описание `employee_name` на     `employee_name = models.ForeignKey(Employee, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name="blank_list")` да и название поля `employee_name` сменил бы на `employee`

для нахождения суммы и среднего значения можно использовать аннотации https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/aggregation/

```
from django.db.models import Avg, Sum

employee_rating_list = Employee.objects.annotate(avg_lvl_1=Avg('blank_list__lvl_1'), avg_lvl_2=Avg('blank_list__lvl_2'), avg_lvl_3=Avg('blank_list__lvl_3'))


for employee in employee_rating_list :
   print(employee.employeename, employee.avg_lvl_1, employee.avg_lvl_2, employee.avg_lvl_3)
```

аналогично и с суммой